# SQL Grouped Rows as Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help to change grouped row as column.

```
ColGroup      Code            
===================
1        A001
1        A001
1        A001   
2        A002
2        A002
3        A003
```

Into

```
1         2       3
===================
A001    A002    A003
A001    A002 
A001
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when colgroup = 1 then code end) as [1],
       max(case when colgroup = 2 then code end) as [2],
       max(case when colgroup = 3 then code end) as [3]
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by colgroup order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Gordon Linoff.

Comment: One more doubt here : Can we change this line "colgroup = 1 then code end) as [1],"  with dynamic value. Since my colgroup is dynamic. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @RajeshBiswas . . . The number of columns returned cannot be changed, unless you use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 2):

I had tried this.I didn't got the exact result but this may be helpful to you http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ecf6c/4

Comment: Thank you Jagadesh for trying this. One doubt can we change this "colGroup = 1"  as dynamic value since my colgroupd is not fixed.

Comment: I don't know whether it is possible in mysqlconsole. But if you are using java database connection your query will be a string. First you get the colGroup values and add it using the looping statement.

Comment: Thank you jagadesh